# How do I reduce the Bitcoin transaction fee?

Tags: transaction-fees, bitcoin-wallet-app

I am using Bitcoin Wallet v5.09-v5.10 on Android 6.0.1. Is there a way to lower the Bitcoin transaction fee?

Comment: Yes, but it depends what wallet software you are using. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the lack of documentation. I am using Bitcoin Wallet v5.09-v5.10 on Android 6.0.1. Yours, Bruce

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use **Send Coins > Options > Fee** to select one of three fee levels. The actual fee is dynamic and depends on the byte size of your payment. Use

- **Priority** if a payment is urgent
- **Normal** if you want confirmation roughly within the next hour
- **Economic** if you don't care about confirmation times (mostly if you're sending to another wallet of yours)